# Unexpected result from reduce method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reduce

I made a function to check if a number is a prime number or not, if not, then it returns the number, otherwise(if it is a prime number) it returns 0.

```
var maybePrimeNumber = [5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 28, 31]; //numbers to test

function isNotPrime(integer){
    var prime = true;            //start off assuming that it is a prime nr for now
    var returnNumber = 0;        //to be returned at the end

    for(i = 2; i<integer; i++){  //go from 2 up to the number,
        if(integer % i === 0){   //if the number is divisible by any nr between 2 and itself, 
            prime = false;       //then say that it isn't a prime number
        }
    }

    if(!prime){                  //if it isn't a prime number, then
        returnNumber = integer;  //prepare to send back the number
    }

    return returnNumber;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = maybePrimeNumber.reduce(
    (total, integer) => {return total + isNotPrime(integer)}
); 
//sum all non-prime numbers up from the array and put the sum into the paragraph "demo"
```

And the problem is as follows:

When I run this, it gives me 75, but it should be giving me 70.

So when I replace the last line with this:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = isNotPrime(maybePrimeNumber[0]);
```

To check if it mistakenly calculates 5 to be a non-prime number - it returns 0, so it doesn't miscalculate.

Why does it give the sum 75 instead of 70 then??

Comment: In your reduce call, specify the 2nd parameter, which is the initial value of `total` - to be `0` - else it'll be the first number in the array, which is `5`, hence your `5` off answer. See: https://jsfiddle.net/88gx55tm/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always include an initial value for `reduce`.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = maybePrimeNumber
  .reduce((total, integer) => {return total + isNotPrime(integer)}, 0);
```

The first value for `total` is the *first element* of the array, if no initial value is included, so `5` is always included in the sum.

Answer (score 0):

The following function works and is cleaner. Note that naming convention would suggest a function names `isSomething` returns a boolean. (Note I used a console.log since I tested this in node).

```js
const maybePrimeNumber = [5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 28, 31]; //numbers to test
function isNotPrime(integer) {
  for(i = 2; i < integer / 2; i++){ //go from 2 up to the number,
    if(integer % i === 0){    //if the number is divisible by any nr between 2 and itself, 
      return true;          //then say that it isn't a prime number
    }
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(maybePrimeNumber.reduce((total, integer) => total + (isNotPrime(integer) ? integer : 0), 0));
```

As @Xufox points out in his answer, your reduction is actually the issue as you should supply an initial value (0) as the second argument to `.reduce()`; otherwise the first value in the array is considered the initial `total` value.